# In a winforms listbox, is there a way to select multiple items in code with only one redraw of the control?

Tags: winforms

I have a listbox that might contain thousands of items. I need a way to select a subset of those with only one control redraw. Right now I'm using the SetSelected method and it forces the control to redraw itself after it selects one item.

Can I use reflection to edit the selecteditems list? Or can I set the control to not redraw itself somehow, select the items, and the turn on redrawing again?

Anyone have any other ideas?

-Isaac

Comment: Why on Earth do you put thousands of items in a ListBox?  Your user has completely lost interest in what's in there by number 50.

Comment: The items are these weird alphanumeric codes of equal length that are sorted but might not be continuous. They select the ones they want to use in a search filter.

Comment: How do you talk a user into picking item number 943?

Comment: How do you find a phone number in the phonebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ListBox.BeginUpdate() / ListBox.EndUpdate brackets for this purpose.

Comment: this does what i want, but it's not speeding up the process any. It still seems to take just as long to select one item.